# How to make api calls for all entries in database if i have to pass individual ids to the query parameter every time i make an api call

Tags: laravel, api

Here I am trying to make an API call to an external API where I have to attach query parameter.

But the problem is the API provider does not allow all parameters at once and is limited to just 10 and I have 75 parameters to attach to the query parameter.

How do I break down the entries from database to chunk and make API calls until all my events are covered.

I tried chunking the query result to 10, then pass them to the query builder function and attach those 10 parameters with comma separation.

But what do I do to make this loop go on till I get all 75 parameters?

EDIT:
I am using Saloon Package for Laravel to make API Requests.
Below is my Request file code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Integrations\BetsApi\Requests;

use App\Http\Integrations\BetsApi\BetsApiConnector;
use App\Models\BetsApi\UpcomingSoccerEvents;
use App\Models\BetsApi\UpcomingSoccerEventsOdds;
use Saloon\Enums\Method;
use Saloon\Http\Request;

class BetThreeSixtyFiveUpcomingSoccerEventsOdds extends Request
{
    /**
     * Define the HTTP method
     *
     * @var Method
     */
    protected ?string $connector = BetsApiConnector::class;
    protected Method $method = Method::GET;
    protected string $description = 'Fetch a list of ODDS for upcoming soccer events from Bet365';

    /**
     * Define the endpoint for the request
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function resolveEndpoint(): string
    {
        return '/v3/bet365/prematch';
    }

    /**
     * Define the query parameters for the request
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function defaultQuery(): array
    {
        // Retrieve all the event IDs from the database
        $eventIds = UpcomingSoccerEvents::pluck('api_event_id')->toArray();
        $eventIdsString = implode(',', $eventIds);

        return [
            'FI' => $eventIdsString,
            'token' => config('services.BetsApi.token')
        ];
    }
}
```

And Below is my Controller i am trying to send request from

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\BetsApi;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Integrations\BetsApi\BetsApiConnector;
use App\Http\Integrations\BetsApi\Requests\BetThreeSixtyFiveUpcomingSoccerEventsOdds;
use App\Models\BetsApi\UpcomingSoccerEventsOdds;
use Filament\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UpcomingSoccerEventsOddsController extends Controller
{
    public function getupcomingsoccereventsodds()
    {

        $connector = new BetsApiConnector();
        $request = new BetThreeSixtyFiveUpcomingSoccerEventsOdds();
        // Create a new instance of the Paginate class

        $response = $connector->send($request);
        $responseArray = json_decode($response, true);
        //dd($responseArray);


                // Create a new model if it doesn't exist
                $model = new UpcomingSoccerEventsOdds();

                // Set the model attributes based on the item data
                // Modify the following code according to your actual model attributes
                $model->FI = isset($item['FI']) ? $item['FI'] : null;
                $model->event_id = $item['event_id'];
                $model->asian_lines = isset($item['asian_lines']) ? $item['asian_lines'] : null;
                $model->goals = isset($item['goals']) ? $item['goals'] : null;
                $model->half = isset($item['half']) ? $item['half'] : null;
                $model->main = isset($item['main']) ? $item['main'] : null;
                $model->schedule = isset($item['schedule']) ? $item['schedule'] : null;

                // Save the new model to the database
                $model->save();
                Notification::make()
                ->title('Upcoming Soccer Events ODDS Saved successfully')
                ->success()
                ->duration(3000)
                ->send();
                 return redirect()->back();
            }



}
```

Comment: you code doesnt make sense, where are you making those api calls ? why fetch the events by id using a collection of ids ? why pluck the ids when you need to fetch the events one by one in the end?

Comment: is your $eventIdsString only showing 10 ids? as @N69S mentioned why using UpcomingCricketEvents to get ids then using UpcomingCricketEvents again to find events?

Comment: i have made the edits and shared my code please check. 
I am using Saloon Package for Laravel to make this API requests. So i am trying to attach the event_ids in FI value as i am requeired by the API provider to pass event_ids in FI query parameter and that i am trying to add via defaultQuery() function.